# How to merge mutiple part of image into one

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I have 100 parts of an image and I want to merge them into one. How can I do it from command line, using tools like Imagemagick's convert or montage.

The input is small parts of an image, like this:

[image: parts of images]

And the output is:

[image: final image]

Answer (score 3):

In Imagemagick, you can use the montage tool to merge an (MxN) array of tiles.

```
montage image01 image02 ... imageXX -tile MxN -geometry +0+0 result
```

If the images are in alphabetic order and say png, then

```
montage *.png -tile XxY -geometry +0+0 result.png
```

See https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/

Here is an example reducing the size by 50%

Input (repeated 4 times):

[image]

```
montage lena.jpg -duplicate 3 -tile 2x2 -geometry 50x50+0+0% lena_montage.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: It is not working. I have 100 image then the result is a black image with resolution 19200x10800. I want the result is 1920x1080 resolution

Comment: `@Phạm Văn Thông`. What is your IM version? If IM 7, then change montage to magick montage.  If your input images are too large, you can resize them with the geometry argument such as -geometry WxH+0+0, where WxH is the desired width and height. Or -geometry WxH+0+0%, where WxH are now percents. Sounds like your images are 10 times larger than you want. So you can use -geometry 10x10+0+0%. Perhaps you can post at least two (separate, but neighboring)  input images and I can test montage of them. I will post an example above.

Comment: Thanks for your supporting. Sorry but I don't had images right now, but I done it by this commands: `convert -layers flatten input*.PNG output.PNG`. I don't want to merge 100 image into one picture. I want to merge 100 of 1/100 part of each image in to one picture.

Comment: `@Phạm Văn Thông` Sorry, I do not understand what you mean by 100 of 1/100 part of each image into one picture! Does that mean you want to 10%x10% crop a the same region of each image and montage them together as I posted above? See my second edit to my original answer. Flattening multiple images will only place them one at a time on top of each other. If they are opaque, then only the last one will show. You need to explain better what you want done!

Comment: `@Phạm Văn Thông`. If you really want to flatten images into one image, they would need to have transparency; otherwise, only the last  image will show. Perhaps what you want, if they are transparent, is the following: `convert input*.png -crop 10x10%+X+Y +repage -background white -flatten output.png`. Where X and Y are the offsets from the top left corner to the common section of each of the images and 10x10% means they will be cropped to 1/100 area at those offsets. I use a white background, but you can change that to any other color. It is not needed if no transparency is left after flatten

Comment: Note that if you are joining images downloaded from HTML canvas element, then the last row and column will probably have smaller images. You can make them "snap" to top and left by using `-mode Concatenate` option, e.g. `montage *.jpg -mode Concatenate -tile 25x30 -geometry +0+0 out.png`

Answer (score 0):

You can combine images vertically or horizontally using `convert` from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php):

```
convert *.PNG -append output.PNG
```

and if you need something faster, use [GraphicMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/):

```
gm convert *.PNG -append output.PNG
```

You can use, `-append` for vertical and `+append` for horizontal attach. Since you need both of these options, my not-a-very-clever solution would be creating the rows first, and them combining those rows vertically to get the final result.